# Unable to transfer files from an on-prem production server to an AWS EC2 in PLE server

Tags: amazon-ec2

How to transfer files from an on-prem production server to an AWS EC2 in PLE server using password-less SCP from the same service account id on the origination and the destination servers?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to setup some authentication on your AWS machine. I assume you would already have key based SSH access to the server. For key based access you can simply execute the below mentioned command:

```
scp -i <path_to_private_key> <source_file_path> username@PublicIP:/tmp/
```

- path_to_private_key is the private key used for SSH to your AWS machine
- source_file_path is the file to be copied
- username is theSSH username used to SSH to your AWS machine
- PublicIP is the IP of your AWS machine